# How to display custom or non-series data array on Highcharts tooltip on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using area range chart with range data on series to display the chart but tooltip doesnot need any of the series data instead I need part of array of data to be displayed on corresponding points. I am not sure which is right way. I already have 3 points of data in series for displaying chart. When I add 5 points to series it became 8 series points. I am not able to get hold of data added dynamically.and additional data from series is messing up my data and I am not able to access exact data added.

So, I tried adding points

```
    tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var points = this.points,
                    point,
                    pointValue,
                    i = 0,
                    j, z = 0,
                    seriesValueHolder = {};
                var bIndex = points[0].point.index;
                var midValue = midPercentiles[bIndex];
                points.push({
                    y: midValue,
                    series: {
                        name: "midSeries"
                    }
                });

                var len = this.points.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    point = points[i];
                    pointValue = point.y;
                    for (j = i + 1; j < len - 1; j++) {
                        pointValue = pointValue + points[j].y;
                    }

                }

    tooltipText += this.renderTooltipLineItem(helper.getSeriesLabel('midSeries'),
                                        seriesValueHolder['midSeries']);
    return tooltipText;

                    },
                    shared: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything works as expected. Thanks for the answers i will try those too. 
works when i tookout the extraline

```
for (j = i + 1; j < len - 1; j++) {
    pointValue = pointValue + points[j].y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Push your custom data in series and get back that on tooltip using

```
this.point.custom
```